# A space S is connected, if except for 0 and S itself, it has no subset whose boundary is empty?

Tags: general-topology

The sphere S2 embedded in E3 is its own interior and closure and hence it has no boundary. An embedded S2 is a subset of E3 with empty boundary. This seems to imply E3 is not connected.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Viewed as a subset of the three-dimensional space, the sphere has a nonempty boundary: the sphere. $S^2$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with empty interior, so $\partial S^2 = \overline{S^2}\setminus \overset{\Large\circ}{S^2} = S^2\setminus \varnothing = S^2$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that the boundary of $S^2$ is itself? Any ball centered at a point on $S^2$ will hit things outside of $S^2$..

Comment: Daniel - Why is the interior empty? If the open sets are induced from E3 isn't the interior then also the sphere?

Comment: I guess its because in the open ball topology of E3 no subset of S2 is an open set and thus the interior is empty? Is that right?